# Calculate the given integral

Tags: integration

Calculate the integral $$\int e^x x^{1/2} \, dx.$$Does integration by parts work alongwith some clever substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Substitute $u^2=x,\; 2 u\;\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}x$.

$$\int e^x \sqrt x \;\mathrm{d}x = 2 \int e^{u^2} u^2\;\mathrm{d}u$$

Then proceed with integration by parts.

However, do note that the integral: $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int e^{u^2}\mathrm{d}u = \operatorname{erfi}(u)$, which is the definition of a special function: [the imaginary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).  It cannot be expressed using elementary functions.

The result you should get is:

$$\int e^x \sqrt x \;\mathrm{d}x = e^x \sqrt x - \frac {\sqrt\pi}2 \operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt x)\color{gray}{+\text{constant}}$$